# Jmeter (JMX) running on GIThub) encounters an error

Tags: github, jmeter, gitlab-ci, performance-testing, cicd

I tried to run my JMX file on Github however I'm encountering an error. can someone help me fix this. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you.

PerfAction for Jmeter
Screenshot:

[image]

YAML File

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your test plan is using [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) and your JMeter installation doesn't have this Dummy Sampler plugin installed.

Make sure to add it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) (it can also be done in [command-line mode](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)) and this error will go away.

If your script uses other [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - do the same for all the plugins used.

Comment: may I know what should I do to make this one works? because on my local it works but on my GIT it doesn't I'm aware that there's missing on my GIT but not sure how to add these plugins I used on my local.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing a similar issue where it cant open the jmx file or unable to find it. I am using nearly same yml file.

Comment: It works for me now. Required a minor fix! Thanks